# Entity framework invalid column discriminator even if Entity.Map<MyEntity>().Map specified

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have TPH inheritance. In OnModelCreating I specify mapping like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
   .Map<Child1>(m=>m.Requires("TypeCode").HasValue("A"))
   .Map<Child2>(m=>m.Requires("TypeCode").HasValue("B"))
   ...
```

However when I try to run the query

```
Parents.OfType<Child1>()
```

I get an error 'Invalid column discriminator'. When debugging I can see it runs the code in OnModelCreating... It seems like EF is ignoring Map definitions?

Comment: Sorry, solved it, my errors was that I was adding the Map methods in OnModelCreating and then added a ParentMap to the configuration. Solved it by moving map methods from OnModelCreating to the ParentMap class. Apparently the ParentMap configuration was overriding the mappings in OnModelCreating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment added to the post describing the problem and solution